# How to make a multi field reference multiple content types?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to implement a Project Member relationship but I don't know how to do that. I have as a content types: Project, Member and Position as the attached UML diagram shows. My doubts are about the team field in Project.

[image: uml diagram of database structure]

I need to relate team members with a certain positon (which can be different from default position) to the Project. One way would be to create another content type called ProjectMember, but I'm trying to avoid that.

What would be the fastest vs the most elegant way to implement that?

Is [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module a suitable way to go?

Comment: I am glad that my answer was useful for you, good luck in your projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

- **Project** (Content Type)
- **Member** (Content Type)
- **Position** (Taxonomy - Because maybe you want to classify)

In **Member** you will have a field that is a Term Reference to **Position**.

In **Project** you will have a [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) named **Project Position**, which will have an [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to **Member** and a field that is a Term Reference to **Position**.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*Project Position (The Collection)*"? I'm confused ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Project Position is the Field Colecction field, I edited the answer. If you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: Paragraphs seems to replace Field Collection module. How could I implement your solution using Paragraphs?

Comment: @geraldo is a little different because you need to know how paragraph works, you can check some articles and made the same steps with paragraph. https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/creating-landing-pages-drupal-8-and-paragraphs https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-powerful-container-paragraphs-in-drupal-8/